# Grunt.js - Warning: Unable to write "filepath" file (Error code: EPERM)

Tags: gruntjs

Getting the following warning message in Grunt.js:

```
Warning: Unable to write "filepath" file (Error code: EPERM). Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
Process terminated with code 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, remove the `Read-only` property from the parent folder's Properties.